# git merge squash non-consecutive commits

Tags: git

I have a few non-consecutive commits on the master branch that I'd like to flatten into one commit. How do I squash `a`, `b`, and `c` if I have the following commits?

> `a-b-x-y-c`

(`a` is the newest commit)

The expected result would be:

> `D-x-y`

(`D` is the squash of `a`, `b`, and `c`). Is this even possible?

Comment: The result will be `D-x-y'` because you're removing `c`. Is this work you haven't yet pushed, *i.e.*, where rewriting history won't cause problems?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Sure, check out [git interactive rebasing](http://book.git-scm.com/4_interactive_rebasing.html).